# Using a custom class name to deserialize a json having a different rootname

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a json having the following structure:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "listingPrice": "free",
            "shortDescription": "desc",
            "title": "one",
        },
        {
            "listingPrice": "free",
            "shortDescription": "desc",
            "title": "two",
        }

    ]

}
```

The corresponding classes are:

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "results"
})
public class ResultsHolder {
    @JsonProperty("results")
    private List<Results> results = null;

    @JsonProperty("results")
    public List<Results> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    @JsonProperty("results")
    public void setResults(List<Results> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Results {

    @JsonProperty("listingPrice")
    private String listingPrice;
    @JsonProperty("shortDescription")
    private String shortDescription;
    @JsonProperty("title")
    private String title;

//getters and setters...
}
```

Reading it as

```
objMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
ResultsHolder res = objMapper.readValue(new URL(url), ResultsHolder.class);
List<Results> cons  = res.getResults();
```

1) Now I dont want my class to be called Results but Listing. How can I do that?

2) Is it possible to avoid the ResultsHolder and instead read the json directly as a List or an Array?

Comment: For your 1st question, what did you mean "I don't want my class to be called Results but Listing"? You can just refactor it with new name. BTW, you don't have to add `@JsonProperty` for each variable or method because their names are the same as field names in JSON string.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can change your `class` name to any thing you want instead of Results but you have to make sure about the object name to be results in ResultsHolder `class`
2. Yes it is possible, In order to read list directly

   `List<Results> cons = objMapper.readValue(new URL(url), new TypeReference<List<Results>>(){});`

For detail you can check [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-json/jackson-objectmapper.html)

Comment: Thanks for 1) I was also changing the variable name when i was trying. Can you elaborate on 2?